# Meaning of "Less Applied"

Tags: phrase-meaning

**[SOURCE](https://ugadmissions.nust.edu.pk/)**   (One of scores)

I often see an educational website using the phrase "less applied" but can't find out what does that mean actually. One sentence comprising this phrase is as follows:

> 1st Selection List of Undergraduate Programmes (***Less Applied***
>   Biosciences) has been uploaded.

Comment: Could you add a link and/or an example with some context?

Comment: Are you sure that _"Less"_ is capitalized? If not, _"less Applied Biosciences"_ means _"with the exception of Applied Biosciences"_

Comment: No it isn't capitalized actually, I did it to place emphasis on this phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a use of the adjective *less* to mean "subtracted from a whole" or "with the exception of". The confusion arises in the capitalization of "less", which makes it appear to modify the degree of the adjectival "applied".

The OED has:

> 4. Preceding (†formerly also, following) a numeral or other quantitative expression, used to denote that the number or quantity indicated is to be subtracted from a larger one mentioned or implied; = minus v.   Also transf., used (like *minus*) for ‘not including’, ‘except’.
>    1911   *Rep. Labour & Social Conditions in Germany (Tariff Reform League)* III. vi– vii. 20   All meat is sold less the bone.

The meaning of the description is thus:

> 1st Selection List of Undergraduate Programmes (**except for** Applied Biosciences) has been uploaded.